# Can I get ido-mode-style completion for searching tags in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, tags

Is it possible to use ido-mode completion to find definitions in a TAGS file?  I suspect that ido-completing-read is part of the answer.  Here's my non-working code, which shows an unpopulated ido-mode minibuffer:

```
(defun ido-choose-from-tags ()
  "Use ido to select tags "
  (interactive)
    (etags-tags-apropos
     (ido-completing-read "Tags: "  nil t)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of inefficient, but how about:

```
(defun my-ido-find-tag ()
  "Find a tag using ido"
  (interactive)
  (tags-completion-table)
  (let (tag-names)
    (mapc (lambda (x)
            (unless (integerp x)
              (push (prin1-to-string x t) tag-names)))
          tags-completion-table)
    (find-tag (ido-completing-read "Tag: " tag-names))))
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  One bug:  when a tag contains a period, it inserts a backslash in front of it, preventing emacs from from finding the tag.

Comment: Replacing the last line with "(find-tag (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\" ""
        (ido-completing-read "Tag: " tag-names)))))" seems to work.

Comment: Good catch.  prin1-to-string can also take an optional 2nd argument that doesn't escape chars, so maybe (prin1-to-string x t) would fix it also.

Comment: Yeah, it does.  That's a much better solution than the regex replace.

Answer (score 1):

To find definitions i use CEDET's command semantic-ia-fast-jump, that together with gtags from GNU Global gives proper and quick navigation through source files.

Comment: Indeed, but `ido-mode` completion for `semantic-complete-jump` and `semantic-complete-jump-local` would also be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, this is EMACS.  What does the non-working code do that tells you it isn't working?

My first suspicion is that it might work better if you used `tags-apropos` (see about line 1885 in etags.el), seeing as `etags-tags-apropos` isn't defined and all.

Answer (score 0):

See also, as an alternative: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Emacs_Tags_Enhancements

Answer (score 0):

An expansion of scottfrazer's solution:

```
(defun my-ido-find-tag ()
  "Find a tag using ido"
  (interactive)
  (tags-completion-table)
  (let* ((initial-input
          (funcall (or find-tag-default-function
                       (get major-mode 'find-tag-default-function)
                       'find-tag-default)))
         (initial-input-regex (concat "\\(^\\|::\\)" initial-input "$")))
    (find-tag (ido-completing-read
               "Tag: "
               (sort
                (remove nil
                        (mapcar (lambda (tag) (unless (integerp tag)
                                                (prin1-to-string tag 'noescape)))
                                tags-completion-table))
                ;; put those matching initial-input first:
                (lambda (a b) (string-match initial-input-regex a)))
               nil
               'require-match
               initial-input))))
```

This puts tags matching tag-at-point at the head of the list. I guess you could secondarily sort by buffer-file-name if two tags match, but that might not always be what you want. Might be faster to use https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-ends-with-suffix-s-optional-ignore-case than string-match for really huge tags tables.