# Get a list of all tags in emacs

Tags: emacs, etag

Is there a way to get all of the tags from the files defined in your tags table list? I've set my tags file like this:

```
(setq tags-table-list '("~/project/TAGS"))
```

I've tried `(tags-completion-table)`, but it doesn't contain all the tags.

Comment: TAGS table is normally used for using Emacs to look up the tags.  So it should be sufficient that Emacs looks at the TAGS.  Do you have any other use in mind besides looking up the tags table using Emacs/etags?

Comment: Yes, I'd like a list of all the tags so I can pass it to ido-read-completing.

Comment: Sounds like related to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476887/can-i-get-ido-mode-style-completion-for-searching-tags-in-emacs

Comment: Definitely related, but not answered. Tags-completion-table

Answer (score 1):

If you got only one TAGS file, `M-x visit-tags-table` `~/project/TAGS` or `(visit-tags-table "~/project/TAGS")` should load the TAGS table into a buffer which means it becomes accessible to Emacs in the same way it would be used for, `M-x tags-search`.

If you add more TAGS files to the project or have more than one project, `(setq tags-table-list '("~/project1/TAGS" "~/Project2/TAGS" ...))` and doing `(visit-tags-table-buffer t)` should visit the next table each time it is called, until the end of the list.

EDIT:

```
(defvar buffer-in-string)
(defvar string-list)
(defun write-buffer-to-string ()
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-in-string (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))
  (kill-buffer) ;; If the buffer is big, it makes sense to kill it,
                ;; since its contents are copied into the string anyway
  (setq string-list (split-string buffer-in-string " "))
)
```

That should bring the buffer into a string.  There should be a more elegant way, but at the moment, this is the most I could write with my very limited elisp fluency.

Comment: is there a way to turn that buffer into a list of strings made up of the tag names so I can pass it to ido-read-completing?

Comment: I don't know how to turn the tags alone into strings, I wrote a small piece of code that turns the whole buffer into a big string.  Which version of Emacs has got the ido-read-completing?  I couldn't find it on mine (Emacs 23.2.1 on Debian testing).

Comment: I'm using gnu emacs 23.3.1 on macos. I'll see what I can do with this, at first glance it looks like it's on the right track. You should really check out ido, it's great: [ido on emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings)

Answer (score 0):

Function `tags-completion-table` gives you a completion table to use.  From the doc string:

`Build 'tags-completion-table' on demand.
The tags included in the completion table are those in the current
tags table and its (recursively) included tags tables.`

And `tags-lazy-completion-table` gives you a completion function to use.  It uses `tags-completion-table`.